# Can I utilize sharepy wtih a card reader and pin code?

Tags: sharepoint, databricks

I'm trying to connect my databricks environment with my company sharepoint using sharepy.  However, I don't have a username and password as I instead log in with an access card and pin code.  Is there a way to utilize sharepy with this information?